# Extract http urls from a string of multiple urls

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a huge string of multiple URLs in javascript which is of the following format:

```
var urls = "http://..... , http://..... , http://......"
```

I need to extract all URLs from the string into individual variables of part of an array. I cant do a urls.split(",") as some urls seem to have commas in them.Is there a good regex I can use to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split on a larger string: `", http://"` — that avoids the problem of commas in the middle of URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know for a fact that the URLs are separated by " , "?  If so, split on that!

Comment: As i told you, URLs can within them have commas.. So split(",") doesnt work.. :(

Comment: @paypal - @zigdon said split(" , "). I.e. there are spaces around the comma. Can your URLs contain commas with spaces around them? If not, his answer works. If so, try @Paul's solution, if all the URLs are absolute and use the http scheme (not https).